# Migrating from MySQL to SQL-Server and index key size is too big

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm moving a DB from MySQL to SQL Server using the SSMA tool. I only get one error when looking into it. Apparently one index in one column is to big (over 900 bytes).

> M2SS0020: SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySql Error message:
>   Index Key size exceeded(1) Estimated manual conversion time: 1.5
>   hr(s)1 table

So I tried to find what index was to big. And It's a text column that is looking a bit strange. But I selected the biggest entries and the largest one is 181 (bytes). I used octet_length() to get the size.

```
SELECT (octet_length(customer_number)) as customer_length, customer_number 
FROM [table] 
ORDER BY customer_length DESC;
```

My question is is this just a warning or a real problem? Is my query wrong to get the size of the indexes? And how can I solve it?

Edit:

```
CREATE TABLE `[table]` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_number` text,
  `who` text,
  `what` text,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` text,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `index_1` (`customer_number`(8))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4462936 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Also, big thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you post the DDL for the table and the index in question?

Comment: I edited the original post with DDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the datatype mapping. To be on the safe side, manually define a mapping for this column to 'NVARCHAR(200)', or some other sufficient size. Here's a useful link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/04/29/converting-from-mysql-to-sql-server-working-with-data-types.aspx